# Calculating average of list of data from sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to make a program that pulls a column of data from sqlite3 and use it to calculate different things (average, stdv, etc.)
Here is what I have so far and the issue I am running into:

```
from math import *
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('personinfo.sqlite3')

def main():
    ages_iterator = conn.execute("SELECT age from person")
    age_list = [a[0] for a in ages_iterator]

    # average age
    average = (sum(age_list))/len(age_list)
```

I am receiving the following error:
   average = (sum(age_list))/len(age_list)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

How can I correct the way I pull the data so I can calculate the average from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this

```
age_list = [int(a[0]) for a in ages_iterator]
```

lists are defaulted to strings and it is falling on you doing mathematical operations with them, by declaring them to integers then it knows you want them to be numbers.

Comment: Ah thank you!! I now however have the issue that some of my data does not have the age listed, but instead "NA"   so now I get this error: age_list = [int(a[0]) for a in ages_iterator]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA' I was able to correct this by just pulling age where it does not equal NA. Thank you for your help